# Start-Job PHP Script Not Working in Powershell?

Tags: php, powershell

I have a PHP script that looks like:

```
if(file_exists("temp.txt")){
    $myfile = fopen("temp.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
}
else{
    $myfile = fopen("temp.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
}
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
$text = $date . PHP_EOL;
fwrite($myfile, $text);
fclose($myfile);
```

When I run the above script in Powershell using

```
php myscript.php
```

A text file is created and written into.

If I try to run the same file with

```
Start-Job ScriptBlock {php myscript.php}
```

I'll get a response like

[image]

But my text file is never written into.  It seems like `Start-Job` never starts my PHP script.

How do I get `Start-Job` to start running PHP scripts?

Comment: Any return from a stop-job and receive-job ? I'm thinking about a path problem needing a full path to php and to the script but I'm not really used to powershell, so it's just an idea.

Comment: @Tensibai No response from either `stop-job` or `receive-job`.  I've tried providing the full path to the `php.exe` in place of shorthand `php`, but still no dice

Comment: Same for the myscript.php (with full path) ? But it should exit with an error file not found if it can't find it. Does call to get-job return it still running ? you may also have a look at the processes with task manager to see if a php process was launched or not... (giving ideas as they come)

Comment: I don't know how your php is configured, for my part I had to add open and close tags in the php file for it to works (even outside the powershell) but it works with `Start-Job -ScriptBlock { D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe -a D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\test.php }` (I had to add a `-` before Scriptblock ... For sanity check I added an echo inside the script and I got it with receive-job

Comment: But just rechecked and the file seems not being created, not in the current dir at least. So I think here lies the problem, a scriptblock may be started in another directory, searching about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'll write an answer about all of this:

From test (with your script as origin) I added some echo to get something in Receive-Job in powershell.

It was obvious the script was running as intended, but not in the expected directory.

So I added a `getcwd()` within an echo and this show me the working dir for the job (or scriptblock) is my documents directory) and I found the file there wihtin my home\documents.

Here the final script I eneded with:

```
echo "I'm running in ".getcwd()." !\n";

if(file_exists("temp.txt")){
    $myfile = fopen("temp.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
}
else{
    $myfile = fopen("temp.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
}
echo "Ok, file was opened: \n".print_r(fstat($myfile),1)."\n";
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
$text = $date . PHP_EOL;
$r=fwrite($myfile, $text);
echo "Write in file returned $r \n";
fclose($myfile);
echo "File closed\n";
```

And that is the output is with Powershell:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\test.php }

Id              Name            State      HasMoreData     Location             Command
--              ----            -----      -----------     --------             -------
51              Job51           Running    True            localhost             D:\wamp\bin\php\php5....
```

And retrieving the output:

```
Receive-Job 51
I'm running in C:\Users\my_name\Documents !
Ok, file was opened:
Write in file returned 24
File closed
```

Hope it will help.